# Why 2nd decorator don't finish his job before finishing the job of 1st decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm a newbie.

Now I’m stuck with a Decorator.

The problem is why doesn’t the 2nd decorator end his job, but, pause. 
And Why after finishing the 1st decorator, the 2nd decorator finish his job?

the Function

```
def document_it(func):
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Running function:', func.__name__) 
        print('Positional arguments:', args)
        print('Keyword arguments:', kwargs)
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Result:', result)
        return result
    return new_function
```

1st Situation

```
@document_it
def add_ints(a, b):
    return a + b

add_ints(3, 5)
```

1st Situation result : Look Carefully Running function!

```
Running function: add_ints
Positional arguments: (3, 5)
Keyword arguments: {}
Result: 8
```

2nd Situation !!!!!!!!!!!

```
@document_it
@document_it
def add_ints(a, b):
    return a + b

add_ints(3, 5)
```

2nd Situation result : Look carefully. Running function: new_function is FIRST!!!!

```
Running function: new_function #seems 2nd's
Positional arguments: (3, 5) #seems 2nd's
Keyword arguments: {} #seems 2nd's
Running function: add_ints #seems 1st's
Positional arguments: (3, 5) #seems 1st's
Keyword arguments: {} #seems 1st's
Result: 8 #seems 1st's
Result: 8 #seems 2nd's
```

Why 2nd decorator didn't finish his work(2nd decorator didn't print his Result), but suddenly 1st decorator come up?

Comment: See https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#nesting-decorators for why nested decorators behave this way. If you use 2 different decorators tha tprint different things at the start and end, it will help you understand the execution path python is taking through your code.

Comment: You aren't applying two decorators to `add_ints`; you are applying `document_it` to `add_ints`, then applying `document_it` to the function returned by the first `document_it`. Decoration occurs when the function is *defined*, not when you call `add_ints`.

Comment: Also, your output (which should be included in the question as text, rather than in a linked image) does not correspond to `document_it` as defined here, which produces no output and merely calls the wrapped function.

Comment: @chepner Oh! that's my mistake. Thank you for helping me. I've just fixed it. could you review it, please? and I've noticed that "result = func(*args, **kwargs)" is something important.

Comment: why "result = func(*args, **kwargs)" calls the wrapped function? isn't it just assignment?

Comment: It's an assignment, but it calls `func` and assigns the return value to the name `result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoration is just syntactic sugar for function application. Your original code

```
@document_it
@document_it
def add_ints(a, b):
    return a + b

add_ints(3, 5)
```

is equivalent to

```
def add_ints(a, b):
    return a + b

add_ints = document_it(document_it(add_ints))

add_ints(3, 5)
```

Each call to the decorator creates a new function which wraps and calls the decorated function.

---

If you modify your decorator slightly:

```
def document_it(func):
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Running function:', func.__name__) 
        print('Positional arguments:', args)
        print('Keyword arguments:', kwargs)
        print('Function id: ', id(func))
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Result:', result)
        return result
    return new_function
```

You'll see that each function that gets called is different: `add_ints` is now really a stack of 3 functions, consisting of the original `add_ints` and the functions returned by each use of the decorator.

```
>>> print(id(add_ints))
4558720608
>>> add_ints(3, 5)
Running function: new_function
Positional arguments: (3, 5)
Keyword arguments: {}
Function id:  4558720032
Running function: add_ints
Positional arguments: (3, 5)
Keyword arguments: {}
Function id:  4558719888
Result: 8
Result: 8
```

`4558719888` is your original, undecorated function that actually adds two numbers; `4558720032` is `new_function` created by the "inner" decorator, and `4558720608` is the `new_function` created by the "outer" decorator, which is what the name `add_ints` is now bound to.

Comment: I've tested the other code. I finally understood how return works in multiple decorator.
after original having conducted, return is changed. 
`def document_it(func):
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Running function:', func.__name__)
        print('Positional arguments:', args)
        print('Keyword arguments:', kwargs)
        print('Function id: ', id(func))
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Result:', result * result)
        return result * result
    return new_function`